# When one of the variable null pull the other one

Tags: merge

i need to use sql and I have table as below;

```
  id      value1     value2
  234        45         null
  145        null        55
```

so need to make one value , remove the null data. the data grouped 2. half of them has value 1, half of them value 2

```
   id   value
   234   45
   145   55
```

coalesca didnt works, so which for this

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem. Also what have you tried so far and which programming language are you using? Are these database tables and you want a SQL query? It's impossible to answer the question in its current state.

Comment: i have a table, and need to modify it. i gave both table examples. tried coalesca function but didnt work. im thinking another function?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what the query would look like using your example table:**

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(value1, value2) AS value
FROM your_table
```